# Should the second thread wait for main thread

Tags: c#, multithreading

When I started main thread I also started a second thread, but the second thread still waits for the main thread. I expected that when I started a new thread it would go do work without being connected to the main thread.  So why does `panel1` become visible after the main thread finishing its job?

```
    private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(threadUI));
        thread.Start();

        // This class is loading something from the server on the main thread
        excel.get_data_from_excel(comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString(), this);
    }
    private void threadUI()
    {
        if (panel1.InvokeRequired)
        {
            panel1.Invoke(new newDelegate(threadUI));
        }
        else
        {
            panel1.Visible = true;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

The `Invoke` method will not return until the main thread executes the delegate. If you want the background thread to continue without waiting for the main thread, use `BeginInvoke` instead.

However, be aware that only one thing can be occurring on the main thread. You can call Invoke or BeginInvoke, but the delegate won't be processed until the main thread is idle. That is, if get_data_from_excel takes a long time, your `panel1.Visible=true` will not take effect until get_data_from_excel completes, comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged_1 returns, and the main thread becomes idle.

If you truly want to make these things "parallel", you must execute get_data_from_excel in a background thread.

Comment: i will change that line to this : panel1.BeginInvoke(new newDelegate(threadUI)); // but it still waiting for mainThread for become visible

Comment: This won't help him solve his problem.  Not having the second thread blocking by using `BeginInvoke` will change one symptom of the problem without fixing the root problem.

Comment: See my edits. I think you have a larger issue than Invoke/BeginInvoke.

Answer (score 1):

You're doing long running non-UI work in the UI thread.

The second thread that you create is doing nothing but calling `Invoke` and doing a bit of work.  What `Invoke` *does* is run some code in the UI thread, which is currently busy doing some non-UI work.  It won't be scheduled to run until after that work finishes.

What you should do is do that long running non-UI work in another thread, rather than the UI thread.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're confused about `Invoke()`.

`Invoke()` is used to queue up a delegate for the thread that displays `panel1`.  However, `Invoke()` **blocks UNTIL** that delegate has run to completion.  Therefore, you have your second thread blocking at `Invoke()`.

If you would like to have an action run on the main thread, while calling it from the second thread **WITHOUT blocking**... then use `BeginInvoke()`.  It will queue up the delegate and then return immediately.

**Servy's Comment**

Servy brings up a good point.  Whats the point of the second thread, if it is just going to immediately call the first?  There isn't any need to create a second thread if you are just going to immediately adjust a control's property.

But it looks like you are grabbing data from excel.  That section of code should be in the second thread... and then with it's output use `BeginInvoke()`.

Comment: This won't help him solve his problem.  Not having the second thread blocking by using `BeginInvoke` will change one symptom of the problem without fixing the root problem.

Answer (score 0):

> if i use code just like this it also waiting for the complete next
>   line finishing its job

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    panel1.Visible = true;
    excel.get_data_from_excel(comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString(), this);
}
```

Comment: i now it's stregth question but i am also new C# and try to figure out it

Comment: Here you're still blocking the UI thread, so the panel's visibility won't be changed until after the operation completes.